# Is there any chance to change ngModel value when clicked <a> tag from loop <a> tags

Tags: angular6, angular-ngmodel, ngmodel

- Hello every one
- am using angular 6 and am new for this
- i have tried change the value in anchor tag ngModel value in loop multiple  tags(its a tags generated using *ngFor).
- **My html code**

> ```
> <a class="layerCss" [(ngModel)] = "clickStatus" [(ngModel)] = "layerStatus" (click)="layersClicks($event)" id="layerTwo">LayerOne</a>
>
> <a class="layerCss" [(ngModel)] = "clickStatus" [(ngModel)] = "layerStatus" (click)="layersClicks($event)" id="layerOne">LayerTwo</a>
> ```

-**My component ts code**

```
@Input() clickStatus: string = 'inactive';
@Input() layerStatus: string = 'offline';
layersClicks(event) {
console.log('content ', (content.target as Element).id);
if(clickStatus === 'inactive') {
....some logic
// here need layerStatus also
this.clickStatus = 'active'
}else {
...some logic
//here need layerStatus also
this.clickStatus = 'inactive'
}
}
```

- when click on LayerOne then LayerOne and LayerTwo both of  tag clickStatus changed to inactive to active.
- but need only, when click event  tag then change clickStatus value theat clicked tag value
- thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood how `[(ngModel)]` works.

`[(ngModel)]` won't work on `<a>` since it has no apparent value. I think what you might want to use to change the value inside the `<a>` tag is the interpolation (`{{}}`).

Unless what you're asking is more on custom attribute inside the `<a>` tag, e.g.: `<a active>`?

Comment: thanks for replay, i have tried [https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-custom-attribute-directive-example] also but am confused  and tried with [clickStatus] = "clickStatus" - its also changed the inactive to active in all <a> tag values.. i need single clicked <a> tag value changes..